# How to get the ID token from FirebaseAuth

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter

I am reading some Json files from my firebase database and I am trying to obtain an ID token for the current user to be used in the header as follows:

```
 var response = await httpClient.get(url,headers: {'Authorization':"Bearer ${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.getToken()}"});
```

when I do the previous line, it seems that it does not get the correct token as I can not access the database, however, when I manually include an ID token in the string, my application works as intended. What is it exactly that I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Aziza, do you know how often are the public keys (for verification) changed? thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[`getIdToken()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.User.html#getidtoken) returns a `Future` - you have to `await` it to actually get the token string:

```
var token = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().getIdToken();
var response = await httpClient.get(url,headers: {'Authorization':"Bearer $token"});
```

Comment: Seems currentUser.getToken() is deprecated.

Comment: Cool, any alternative?

Comment: `getIdToken` - https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.User#getIdToken

Comment: This getIdToken() method seems to not be available with current flutter firebase_auth.???

Comment: did you find a way to get the token? seems like getIdToken() and getToken() are not available with firebase_auth

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/lib/src/firebase_user.dart#L36

Comment: Hi @rinukkusu any ide how to get tokenId ? Because above link is 404 not found

Comment: It's still the same - here's the link to the current location of the source code of the `firebase_auth` package: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/lib/src/firebase_user.dart#L36

Comment: // Using firebase@9.0.1

import * as firebaseAuth from "firebase/auth";
firebaseAuth.getAuth(firebaseApp);
await firebaseAuthInstance.currentUser?.getIdToken();

Answer (score 6):

I think that there is a bug in Flutter.

Now to call the method `getIdToken()` you need to do this:

```
FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();

String token;

user.getIdToken().then((result) {

    token = result.token;
});
```

You can't call `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().getIdToken()`

Comment: This was the solution which worked for me after lot of trial and errors. But I have to add await before user.getIdToken()....

Answer (score 1):

U can also retrieve the id token from the window object like so:

```
const idToken = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getAuthResponse().id_token
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with

```
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
```

then you can access the token with

```
var token = await response.user.getIdToken();
console.log('TokenID', token);
```

and after that, you can use it into

```
var response = await httpClient.get(url,headers: {'Authorization':"Bearer $token"});
```