# Check if user logged in from backend Firebase Authentication

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

In my frontend, the user logs in using Firebase Authentication Browser. That part works perfectly fine. In addition to Firebase backend, I also have NodeJS backend that serves additional content. However, I need to serve the content to only Authenticated user.

My question is: Is there a way for my NodeJS backend to know that a user has been authenticated when they make a request?

Comment: Try to have a look here. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An authenticated client is issued an [ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users#auth_tokens) that uniquely identifies the user.  The client can [get this this token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45563320/how-to-get-the-id-token-from-firebaseauth) using the provided API.  Then, it can pass that token to external APIs, which is [verify the token using the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens).

Comment: just a silly question. Does the admin sdk and the frontend sdk which the user used to authenticate must be on the same project? Or can a project A using this token verification on a user who is authenticated with project be?

Comment: The Admin SDK must be initialized with some credentials from the same project as the one the client app is using to log in. That's how they effectively share data.

Comment: But how do you redirect user to a new page