# Redirecting user to a new page after successful login with Firebase

Tags: firebase, express, google-app-engine, routes, firebase-admin

I have a web app and I am using firebase authentication to login/signup our users.

In the past I have used Passport for login in my app which works but you have to maintain your own database and security blah blah... but I can control when my user can visit a page after logging via Passport using middleware like this -

```
// isAuthentcated is my middleware on server side. 

app.get('/home', isAuthenticated,(req,res)=>{
   res.render('home');
});
```

How can I do the same using firebase because there isn't any mechanism to do that. I have read different answers on stackoverflow and most of the pople are suggesting something like below which obviously isn't secure. Anybody can just type home.html and get to the page.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if(user) {
    window.location = 'home.html'; //After successful login, user will be redirected to home.html
  }
});
```

Although, I have thought of using [firebase-admin sdk token verification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdks) and try to follow the [suggestion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55117541/check-if-user-logged-in-from-backend-firebase-authentication)  but I don't know how it can be useful to do that on server side. Do you guys have any suggestions? How do you redirect user to a new page. An ajax post/get request from a client to a route '/home' with a header containing 'Bearer token' just validate the token but doesn't redirect user because it is a ajax call which is meant for updating a portion of a page.

Now, the question really is, Is it even possible to do that with firebase authentication?

Comment: Where is this web site being hosted? If it's on Firebase Hosting, there is no way to secure access to the hosted files. All files on Firebase Hosting are public. If it's elsewhere, it depends on where that actually is.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Rightnow I am using local express server. I will later upload it to app engine. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you host your site on App Engine you can send the ID token of the client with the request for the HTML. This could take the form of a cookie, a parameter, or whatever you choose to securely transfer the token from client to server.

Then the server can [use the Firebase Admin SDK to verify the ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens), and use whatever logic you need to determine whether the request is authorized.

Comment: As in my last paragraph, I have already described the same method so I understand this part completely. What I am asking, how can I redirect the user after validation? As I have also explained the problem why it isn't working.